# When click on submit button it navigates to New page with same window **dynamically loading** using `meteor`

Tags: meteor, router

I am try to when click on **Form submit button** it navigates to **new page with same window dynamically** but it is not loading the details but it navigates to that page.I am sending my code also please help me.

**Html page**

```
<head>
  <title>sample</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    {{> header}}    
    {{> body}}        
    {{> footer}}
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
   {{render-Router}}
</div>
</body>
<template name="header">
    <header>
        <div class="header"> 
        <a  href="http://localhost:3000/"><img  src="./logo.png" style="height:100px;width:200px;"/></a>
    </div>
    </header>
</template> 
<template name="body">
  <div class="bgbody">
     <div align="center">
    <form id="login-form" action="/admindetails">
        <table>
        <p class="admin">Admin Login</p>
        <tr>
           <td><p for="username">Admin Name</p></td>
           <td><input type="text"  id="username" name="username"  placeholder="UserName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
               <td><p for="password">Password</p></td>
           <td><input type="password" id="pwd" name="password"  placeholder="password"></td>
        </tr>
            <td></td><td><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Log In"></td>
        <td><input class="btn btn-capsule" type="button" value="New User"></td>
        </table>
    </form>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
<template name="footer">
    <div class="footer">
        <div style="padding:20px;">
        <div class="footerlinks"><a href="#"><p>AboutUs</p></a></div>
        <div class="footerlinks">|</div>
        <div class="footerlinks"><a href="#"><p>ContactUs</p></a></div>
        <div class="copyright"><p>Copyright@Healt_Care</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Client code:**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.Router.add({

    '/admindetails':'admindetails'

    })
  Template.body.events
  ({
    'submit #login-form' : function (e,t)
 {
      /* template data, if any, is available in 'this'*/
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')

        console.log("You pressed the button");
         e.preventDefault();
  /*retrieve the input field values*/
         var email = t.find('#username').value
         , password = t.find('#pwd').value;
           console.log(email);
   Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function (err)
    {
    if (err) 
    {
      console.log(err);
      alert(err.reason);
      Session.set("loginError", true);
     }
     else
     {
       console.log(" Login Success ");
       Meteor.Router.to("/admindetails");
     }
    });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault` should be stopping that...

Answer (score 1):

You manage the submit event yourself, so there's no need to set up the `action` parameter of the form. Setting that parameter causes browser to load target page on submit. Simply remove the parameter and things should work as intended.